# JSON Wont Load with React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, reactjs, fetch

I have a Rails 5.1 app with React installed via webpacker.  I have a resource which I have a JSON endpoint for, but when I try to pull this, I get an error on the terminal:

I'm using my local path of `fetch("roasts.json")` which gives 
`Completed 401 Unauthorized in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)`

Or if I use a full path `fetch("https://www.gourmetcoffee.london/roasts.json")` I get no error in the terminal but `Error: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` in the browser.

I've lifted the code pretty much from www.reactjs.org:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

class AllRoasts extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("roasts.json")
      //.then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items
          });
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Brewing...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <ul>
          {items.map(item => (
            <li key={id}>
              {item.name}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  }
}


export default AllRoasts
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with React.  It is an issue with your rails API.  401 means `unauthorized`, so the user (or anonymous user) you are using is not permitted to access that endpoint.

Comment: OK.  This is my own resource. How would I 'grant' permission?

Comment: That's far too vague, sorry.  There are a million different ways to handle permissioning, and I have no context as to how you are currently going about it.  All I can tell you is that you have locked yourself out of your own house.

Comment: ok thanks.  More digging for me!

Comment: Share the controller code where're you rendering desired json.